# Flutter nested GridView.builder disappears when .orderBy("date") is added to FirebaseFirestore stream Query

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a widget that uses a StreamBuilder and GridView.builder which populates perfectly fine with

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("events").where("venueId", isEqualTo: widget.venueId).snapshots()
```

However when I add order by after a split second it refreshes and disappears.

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("events").where("venueId", isEqualTo: widget.venueId).orderBy("date").snapshots()
```

Heres is where im calling it.

```
class VenueGridWidgetVerticalState extends State<VenueGridWidgetVertical> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("events").where("venueId", isEqualTo: widget.venueId).orderBy("date").snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(child: Text('Loading events...'));
        }
        return GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 1,
            mainAxisExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 8,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
```

Is there anyway of me waiting until its ordered to display the results on screen as now it seems to be showing then ordering then disappearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing loading indicator until data is ordered

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("events").where("venueId", isEqualTo: widget.venueId).orderBy("date").snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      // When Data Loading
      return const Center(child: Text('Loading events...'));
    } else if (snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty) {
      // Data fetched but not ordered yet
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    return GridView.builder(
      // ... rest of your GridView code
    );
  },
),
```

This code checks for two conditions:

1. !snapshot.hasData: This indicates data hasn't been fetched yet.
2. snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty: This means data is fetched but still
   empty, likely because ordering hasn't completed. If either condition
   is true, it displays a loading indicator. Once data is fetched and
   has content (snapshot.data.docs is not empty), it builds the
   GridView.

This is a simpler solution that avoids additional streams and logic for ordering flags.

Comment: i need to add my custom loader in this loading part so how to do in this code .?
please suggest me.

Comment: You can replace `Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());` this code and add your custom loading.

Comment: Still seems to  be the same. It seems you cant combine orderby and where together as they work when separate but not together.

Comment: ensure that the date field in your Firestore documents is of a type that can be ordered. If it's not, ordering by date might not work as expected.